# Lexer lib for Python3 capable of creating AST trees

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer, smali

I have been reading some information about lexers in python 3. I liked Plex but it seems not to work with Python 3 (I can install it but it then fires up an error when I try to import it). I know it wasn't able to create AST trees (I was going to do that myself) but now that it seems that do not work I would like to know if there's a good Lexer lib capable of creating AST trees for python 3. I'm going to parse smali files if this is of interest.

Cheers.

Comment: *Androguard* parses DEX files (you are talking about Smali in Android, aren't you). Not sure about AST, but possibly it will be enough for you.

Comment: Not really sure if this is what I need. It seems more like smali/backsmali + other niceties. I just want to create an AST tree from smali classes to do some transformations on it (some kind of ofuscation).

Comment: Yeah. Smali/baksmali - is indeed what it does. On the second hand, obfuscation might be done by directly transforming smali, since the language is quite simple.